# How to flatten/pivot "inner join" into a single row in a certain order?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, pivot

Let's say I have 2 tables in MySql/MariaDb: `competisions` and `participants`. There can be multiple `participants` in one `competisions`.

I want to

- a) do an `inner join`
- b) sort the `participants` by `score`
- c) take top 5 `participants`
- d) flatten the result into a **single row**

A flatten result would have `pt1_name`, `pt1_score` ... `pt5_name`, `pt5_score`  columns

How to do it?

So far I've managed to do the a), b), c)

```
SELECT
      cm.id as 'cm_id',
      cm.title,
      cm.place,

      pt.id as 'pt_id',
      pt.full_name,
      pt.score

FROM competitions as cm
INNER JOIN participants as pt
ON pt.competition_id = cm.id


ORDER BY pt.score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This will produce 5 rows. What I want is 1 row, such that the data from the 4 other rows would get quashed into the 1st row thus making it N columns longer.

**NOTE:** and If I query all the data from all `competitions` at once, it'd have to produce the amount of the flattened rows equal to the amount of rows in `competitions`.

How to do the d)?

Example of a result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name    | title  | ple | p1    |score1| p2    |score2| p3    |score3| p4    |score4 | p5     |score5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
compet1 | title1 | aaa | part1 | 3    | part2 | 4    | part3 | 4.2  | part4 | 30    | part5  | 32   
compet2 | title2 | fds | part1 | 1.33 | part2 | 2.34 | part3 | 2.8  | part4 | 120   | part5  | 150  
compet3 | title3 | ccc | part1 | 4.88 | part2 | 5.25 | part3 | 5.8  | part4 | 8.90  | part5  | 9.23 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This "flatten" is referred to as "pivot". MySQL does not implement it, use conditional aggregation.

Comment: @Akina how to use conditional aggregation in my case?

Comment: See the tag I added.  There are many examples.  And even more in stackoverflow.com with tag [pivot-table]  Be sure to include [mysql] tag also.

Comment: @RickJames why would you add a tag given that I'd already used the word "pivot" in my title?

Comment: Click on the tag to easily find other Questions about the same topic.

Comment: @RickJames I've found them. My question remains

Comment: Use an application language to handle d), SQL is a data retrieval language, use application languages for formatting.

Comment: @danblack don't know one's requirements -  give no advice